# Time between visits without a visa

Tags: visas, schengen

If you go to Italy without a visa and leave at the 90 day mark, how long do you have to stay out of the country before you can return without a visa

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What's your citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

Most European countries I believe will let you stay for 90 days out of 180 consecutive days, so that leaves you about 3 months before you can go back to Europe. I'm assuming you're American
http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/go/schengen-fact-sheet.html

Bear in mind this might be dependent on the treaty Schengen countries have with your country of citizenship

Comment: What if she is not?

Comment: @Karlson yep, I just added a note about that, let's see what she answers, we'll find something more suitable if not. My experience is that it usually is 180d between western countries

Comment: So why not wait for the OP to add citizenship information and then answer the question in the more precise manner?

Comment: In fact it does not matter, apart from extremely rare corner cases (diplomats or refugees with a limited territoriality visa for Italy or these kinds of things), there are only two possibilities: either the person can stay permanently (e.g. EU citizen or non-EU spouse of a EU citizen) or she is making a short stay in the Schengen area (as a resident from another Schengen country or because she has a citizenship that allows visa-free short stays) and the answer is correct.

Comment: Also, we know from the question that she can visit without a visa but only stay 90 days so if she is not a US citizen, she is from another country for which the exact same rules apply.

Comment: I just checked against this (pretty well referenced) article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area